# search, insert & write on a new line of text file using PHP

Tags: php, file

i have problems in searching a string in a file, insert a new line after the searched string and write on the new added line. currently i am using below code from examples and discussion i found:-

```
$target = '<18>';
$put = 'Enter';
$file = 'line.txt';

$filename = $file;
$string_i_am_looking_for = $target;
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
$lines[$string_i_am_looking_for] = $put;
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines ) );
```

text file:-

```
<17>
<18>
<19>
<20>
```

at first action, i was able to put the $put in the text file.

```
<17>
<18>Enter
<19>
<20>
```

but, when i change the $target = "<20>", i was not able to write after the new $target. It will appear next to the first line. And when i reload the page more and more, it will keep on writing on the first line. Below is the result:-

```
<17>EnterEnterEnterEnterEnter
<18>Enter
<19>
<20>
```

Answer (score 0):

Word `Enter` **is not new line in any manner**. You have to replace it with `\r\n` or `\n` (depends on file new line character).

```
$target = '<18>';
$put = "\r\n";
$file = 'line.txt';
```

Comment: yes i know that. it is just a string and not an action.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$target = '<20>';
$put = 'Enter';
$file = 'line.txt';

$filename = $file;
$string_i_am_looking_for = $target;
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
$key = array_search($string_i_am_looking_for,$lines);
$toSearch = $target.$put;
if(!in_array($toSearch,$lines)) {
$lines[$key] = $target.$put;
}
file_put_contents( $filename , implode( "\n", $lines) );
```

Comment: when i load the it more times, the first line will replaced with the $target.    the results in the text file will be like this:- <20>Enter<18><19><20>Enter... where it should be <17><18><19><20>EnterEnterEnter